# URL masking in asp.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have two about pages in my website, "About.aspx" and "OtherAbout.aspx".
Which of these is navigate to is based on the user logged in.
I want to always display About.aspx as the URL even if we are on OtherAbout.aspx, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) method for this purpose

Comment: Will this not physically change the page I am on (i.e. show the about.aspx page, not the OtherAbout.aspx page) rather that just masking the URL?

Comment: User will get responce from OtherAbout.aspx. But he will see the "About.aspx" url in address line of his browser.